# How can I authenticate BigCartel API in a react native mobile app?

Tags: react-native, api, authentication, bigcartel

How to integrate BigCartel API to the react native application?

I want to hear a good experience to integrate BigCartel API to a react native mobile application.
If the user pay for the subscription, then I need to know if the user paid or not using BigCartel API.
That is my first experience, please help me.